# How to connect DimDate table to fact and dimensional tables

Tags: powerbi, business-intelligence, datamodel

I have fact table,Dim project , Dim student & Dim date tables in the power BI model.

- Fact contains studentid,projectid,is submitted, submitted date ,marks
- Dim student contains studentid,joining date, name
- Dim project contains projectid, project creation date, project type

As the requirement I want to showcase following points in one dashboard.

1. Marks based on student joining date
2. Marks based on project creation date
3. Marks based on submitted date

Using one year & month filter using  Dim Date table. Following is the power bi model that I created ,

[image]

So as this,Dim student & dim date / Dim project & dim date relationship is not active.

How I solve this in order to answer above requirements? Is this power bi model is correct or not?

Looking for a reply.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Star schema refers to the logical description of datasets where data is divided into facts tables and dimension tables. ... Therefore, the Authors table will be implemented as a dimension table in a star schema in Power BI. In the same way, the Project and Student tables has been implemented as  dimension tables.

A fact table is the central table in a star schema of a data warehouse. A fact table stores quantitative information for analysis and is often denormalized

So you don't need to join your dimensions to the DIM_DATE.